# Registering WebSite to use Facebook Login Button

Tags: facebook, authentication

Need to register my WebSite to use the FaceBook Login (Register) button.

Can't seem to find it on Facebook and Google does not have anything to help me?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

Comment: Thanks but no.  I need to register my WebSite so I can add my ID to the following type code:
{
   "name": "Facebook Platform",
   "type": "page",
   "website": "http://developers.facebook.com",
   "username": "platform",
   "founded": "May 2007",
   "company_overview": "Facebook Platform enables anyone to build...",
   "mission": "To make the web more open and social.",
   "products": "Facebook Application Programming Interface (API)...",
   "likes": 449921,
   "id": 19292868552,
   "category": "Technology"
}

Comment: No, you don't need a special registration. There is no hidden form somewhere on Facebook where you have to apply for it. All you need is an app (developers.facebook.com/apps) and the proper settings in the app (website url). After this you can start using the registration plugin.